# Accessible collapsible region (without button)

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

In most of the example, and documentation I've found online (eg. https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_WAI-ARIA_aria-expanded_state_to_mark_expandable_and_collapsible_regions) the best way to implement a collapsible section is to use two different elements.

```
<p class="button">
    <button id="button1" class="buttonControl" aria-controls="t1" aria-expanded="false"><span>Show</span> Topic 1</button>
</p>

<div id="t1" class="topic" role="region" tabindex="-1" >
    Topic 1 is all about being Topic 1 and may or may not have anything to do with other topics.
</div>
```

Anyway, in my case the region should be collapsed when the click occurs on the section itself.
My question is how to implement this functionality in an accessibility-friendly way.

**Update**

I make an example, so that is more clear what I want to obtain.
Consider this paragraph:

```
<p>This paragraph contains the first two lines of a bigger section ...</p>
```

When the user click on this paragraph its content should change into the following:

```
<p>This paragraph contains the first two lines of a bigger section, when it gets clicked the whole document is rendered... if it gets clicked again it gets collapsed.</p>
```

Comment: Could you just explain how you have a region that collapses but is clickable - do you mean that the region shrinks and grows in size (as if it is collapsed it should be `display: none` or `aria-hidden`) so it would take some interesting markup to have a 'snippet' that then expands to a full section. The code you showed is a typical example so I am just trying to understand the structure you want to work with.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I've updated the question to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** There isn't a neat way to do this unfortunately (I think) without a screen reader re-reading things but I believe the below is the best compromise. Also please note I haven't tested the below so I may have made mistakes.

The principle doesn't actually change, you need a 'button' (in the loosest sense) and a section that expands.

So you would structure your HTML similar to the following:-

```
<p role="button" tabindex="0" aria-controls="t1" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="button-text" onclick="toggle()">
    <span class="inline" id="button-text">the first part of the snippet
        <span class="hide-when-expanded" aria-hidden="true">...</span>
        <span class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="false">(click to expand snippet)</span>
    </span>
    <span class="the-hidden-part-of-the-text" id="t1" style="display:none"> and this is the second hidden part</span>
</p>
```

### Explanation

The whole paragraph is treated like a button by the screen reader `role="button"` and `tabindex="0"` added to make it focusable.

I added an `onclick` handler for demonstration but obviously you should do this with selectors for the 'toggle' function.

Within the first block of text (visible when collapsed) I added three dots to signify there is more to read for sighted users and hid this from the screen reader.

I also added some visually hidden text (see **visually hidden CSS** at bottom of this answer for the CSS) to explain that there is more content available for screen reader users.

Finally I added the next part of the text in a separate `<span>` that is hidden.

To show the content we then change the above to look like the following:-

```
<p role="button" tabindex="0" aria-controls="t1" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="button-text" onclick="toggle()">
        <span class="inline" id="button-text">the first part of the snippet
            <span class="hide-when-expanded" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none">...</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">(click to expand snippet)</span>
        </span>
        <span class="the-hidden-part-of-the-text" id="t1" style="display:inline-block"> and this is the second hidden part</span>
 </p>
```

We change the `aria-expanded` to 'true' for the parent element.

We hide the three dots and the screen reader explanation.

We show the final span with the additional text.

### Important

As I said this isn't tested, you may find that you need to move the `aria-controls="t1" aria-expanded="false"` onto the first paragraph.

You may also find that you don't need the `aria-labelledby` if that is the case (or at all) that is there, so that the 'button' we created gets read out correctly but as this is an unusual structure it might not be needed.

It is important that the whole paragraph is clickable so that it can be closed easily.

You will have to play with styling to make sure that there is no unusual spacing etc.

You may hear a slight pause between the first part and the second part, certain screen readers do this when encountering multiple spans, there is nothing we can do about it but it actually makes it easier to spot where the additional content starts if this is the case.

I tried this with `aria-live` on the region to try and simplify it, if you were considering that, but it did not provide good behaviour as it meant you had to explain that the region was clickable.

**maybe just go with the accepted way of button to expand** as this way feels messy. You could always position the button after the text visually using CSS.

### visually hidden CSS

```
.visually-hidden { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
}
```

### EDIT - alternative option

We could make this even simpler.

```
<p>the first part of the snippet 
    <span class="hide-when-expanded" aria-hidden="true">...</span>
    <span class="visually-hidden"> and this is the second hidden part</span>
</p>
```

In the above example we follow the same principles (hiding the three dots on open) however we leave all the content accessible at all times to screen reader users.

Then all we need to do is remove the `visually-hidden` class on expand for sighted users.

As screen reader users can skip to the next section easily this is probably a much better option as the only reason to hide content and expand it is for visual appeal.

This removes all the problems with using `aria` for the toggle.

The only thing you need to think about is keyboard users who aren't using a screen reader, without confusing screen reader users (i.e. your toggle is `aria-hidden`).

Comment: Thank you for your aswer and the detailed explaination. I've also thought of a possible solution involving a checkbox, and i'm curious to hear your thoughts about it. It's posted in this page. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: updated my answer with a simpler (and almost certainly better) variation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering the below approach:

```
<div aria-expanded={String(isExpanded)} id="myAbstract" onClick={toggle}>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="" 
    aria-controls="myAbstract"
    aria-label={(isExpanded ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand') + ' the abstract'}
    role="button"
    checked={isExpanded}
    onChange={toggleAbstract}
  />
  {isExpanded && ? fullText : text}
</div>
```

The checkbox is absolute positioned, and visually hidden (opacity: 0) but still focusable; so the user can check it using keyboard. Also, css selector focus-within should allow me to style the paragraph differently when the checkbox is focused.

Comment: Interesting approach (in fact a checkbox is actually better than a toggle button) however there is a problem where you switch the text out on the fly, there is no way for a user to continue reading from where they were. A much simpler option might be to simply visually hide then expanded snippet but always make it accessible to screen reader users. I will edit my answer to add this option.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Are you suggesting that i should modify the snippet like this:

`isExpanded ? <span>{preview}</span><span>{extra}</span> : <span>{preview}</span><span aria-hidden="true">...</span>`

?

Comment: No, ignore `aria` - what I am suggesting is that you just toggle the `visually-hidden` class on the content (visually hidden class makes it accessible for screen readers but invisible to sighted users). In effect make the content always visible to screen readers and make it hidden for sighted users. Then remove the `visually-hidden` class on toggle for sighted users.

Comment: `<span>{preview}</span>` (always visible) and then `isExpanded ? <span>{extra}</span> : <span aria-hidden="true">...</span>`

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you very much.